# Determine if app's iOS 14 widget is placed on the home screen - Swift

Tags: swift, ios14

Is there a way to determine if and how many of your app's widgets are being used by the user?

I tried using

```
WidgetCenter.shared.getCurrentConfigurations { result in
    switch result {
        case let .success(info):
            let myWidgetCount = info.count
            print(myWidgetCount)
        case let .failure(error): print(error)
    }
}
```

but it's way off. It's giving me way more than it should.

Edit: it's including all of the ones I added and later removed as well. Is there a way to get only the ones that are currently placed on their home screen or the widget section?

Comment: I am finding with no widgets installed the widget count starts at 4. Presumably 3 are from the widget select screen... not sure where the extra one is coming from. Did you find the same?

Comment: Found that restarting the device fixed this problem, widget count is 0 with no widgets installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this is an issue with the simulator. On a physical device, it does not include removed widgets.

Answer (score 0):

while I use a device was iOS 14.4 ,and build via Xcode 14.2; I find that getCurrentConfigurations callback with list that include all of the ones I added and later removed